# Is the operation taking a matrix to the power of another matrix well-defined?

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

e.g. if A and B are matrices, is there a useful definition for $A^B$? I don't see an obvious definition; but then the definition of the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) also would never occur to me independently, but it makes perfect sense. Unfortunately I can't see an obvious way to extend that sensible definition into the general operation I'm looking for, since the matrix logarithm is multivalued. Is there a way around this?

Comment: One useful definition would be to constrain $A$ and $B$ to have the same dimensions, then apply $A^B$ as the element-by-element exponentiation.  I am not familiar with any other possibilities...

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable and positive, then I suppose the matrix exponential definition can be used to define $A^B$ accordingly.

Comment: So, claim: you will never, ever need to use this operation. (If you think that the most important property of $e^x$ is that it solves the differential equation $f' = f$, you can be led to the matrix exponential pretty naturally by considering analogous differential equations involving vectors. But I'm not aware of a corresponding motivation for considering $A^B$ where $A, B$ are both matrices.)

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that $A$ is normal and nonsingular (and perhaps a bit more), then you can define $A^B$ by matrix-matrix eponentiation as in http://www.rockefeller.edu/labheads/cohenje/PDFs/215BarrabasCohenalApp19941.pdf, section $3$. Of course, it uses $\exp$ and $\log$ for matrices. To be more precise, $A^B=e^{(\log A)B}$, or
$A^B=e^{B(\log A)}$.
Even exponential product formulas are derived there:
$$
A^{B+C}=\lim_{k\to \infty}(A^{B/k}A^{C/k})^k,
$$
relying on Lie's exponential product formula.