# Is there a definition of matrix power of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are matrices , if there a definition for $A^B$? Of course hopefully it's reasonable , has some application possibility . For example $A^n$ where n is an integer could be defined from multiplication , $\cos A$ could be defined from series...

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466068/is-the-operation-taking-a-matrix-to-the-power-of-another-matrix-well-defined